# how can i know the location of the python module using find command in linux

Tags: python, linux

how can i know the location of the python module using find command in linux
I am quite new with python as well as linux. 
And don't know how to find a particular module or file

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you mean Python executable?

Comment: Also consider shell commands **which** and **locate**

Answer (score 5):

Easier method is to import it from Python and checking the path from there.

For example:

```
python
>>> import statsd
>>> print statsd.__file__
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsd/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

It is faster with:

```
locate module
```

or:

```
locate module.py
```

using find:

```
find /usr -name module.py
```